# Arch Linux shutdown

Tags: archlinux

Whenever I shutdown my Arch Linux system and then restart it I find that the work I did in terminal or I left any window open before shutting down are back again on the screen again , I can find my last used commands by pressing up arrow key on the keyboard . How to just get everything new whenever I boot up my PC .

P.S - I'm new to Arch

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about programming.

Comment: This is a programming Q&A site, not a software help site. There is a site on the network specifically for linux related question. This will probably get closed by mods.

Answer (score 0):

1. Append a line containing `unset HISTFILE` to `~/.bashrc`.
2. Type `unset HISTFILE; rm HISTFILE`.
3. Reopen the terminal.

Bash wiki for further reference: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars#histfile

To revert old behaviour: remove the line that was appended.

Answer (score 0):

You have session restore enabled, You may change it. The process varies from environment to environment. On some DEs (desktop environment) it even asks while shutting down if you want to save that session for future log in.